# genymotion generic unknown error

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I have recently downloaded Genymotion in hopes of having a speedier emulator for working in Android Studio. Everything looks like it downloaded correctly, and I have linked my Genymotion to my Android Studio. The problem is when I try to sign into Genymotion, it keeps saying "unknown generic error." I have contacted Genymotion many times about this issue, and they have not gotten back to me. I even tried re-downloading Genymotion, and creating a new account. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: Try checking the Virtual box installation. Update virtual box if needed.

Comment: Tried uninstalling virtual box and genymotion and reinstalling them. Nothing seemed to help

Comment: Can you post picture of error? 
Check 32 bit/ 64 bit versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your GenyMotion go to:

1. Settings -> Network
2. Check Use HTTP Proxy
3. Insert HTTP Proxy and Port
4. Click "OK"
5. Now try to login genymotion.

Hopefully it helps

Comment: what do you mean with inert? can't do step 3. Please give further info

Answer (score 4):

Mine got resolved by doing the following:
Opening Virtual Box -> Preferences -> Network - > host-only networks -> Edit Virtual Host-Only Ethernet Adapter -> DHCP Server -> uncheck Enable server.

it may help some.

Comment: After I uncheck Enable server , virtual box will create another Virtual Host-Only Ethernet Adapter for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but I solved it by this steps
1. get your Ip address that you use it to enter internet
2. open network and sharing center
3. open virtualbox host-only network
4. put your internet Ip as default gateway and prefered dns server
it should work after that.

Explanation: virtual machine made a network card and give it default IP "192.168.56.1" if this IP can't access internet so you can't login so but your internet ip as default gateway and dns

that's worked for me.

Comment: This is the ONLY way for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I logged in at Genymotion website and then I tried logging in with app. It worked for me.

Comment: I tried everything as mentioned above but it doesn't work. It only work after I login to the website.

Answer (score 1):

Almost like @Flowra mentioned:

- Find the IP address and default gateway of your network (*cmd ->

  ipconfig*).
- Open Network and Sharing Center and click on Virtual Box host only Network.
- Click Properties -> IP4 Properties
- Put your network's default gateway (eg. 192.168.1.1) in the default gateway and your IP address as the Preferred DNS Server

Then restart Genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by enabling network access in AhnLab Internet Security blabla installed in my computer.... That app is blocking the network access in Genymotion...

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue...

### First

Open Virtual Box -> Preferences -> Network - > host-only networks -> Edit Virtual Host-Only Ethernet Adapter -> DHCP Server -> uncheck Enable serve

### Then

Open setting "Open Network and Sharing Center" > Change Adaptor Setting > Right Click on "Virtual Box Host-Only Network" > Properties > Select "Internet Version Protocol 4 (TCP / IPv4)" > Click on "Properties" Tab > Check "Obtain IP Address Automatically" as well as "Obtain DNS Server Automatically"

At this point, the problem still wasn't solved

### Finally

Open Antivirus >Internet & Network > Programme Rules > Allow Genymotion

and it's done!

Answer (score 0):

Try different types of networks. If it fails, click the login-in button more than one time, and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I use window 7 n use Internet Connection by wireless, not LAN cable.

1. Open settiing "Open Network and Sharing Center"
2. I've 2 network :
   2.1 Wireless connection (that have Internet connection)
   2.2 VirtualBox network (that no network to access internet)
3. Check my IP Address from wireless connection (2.1)
   Example : 192.168.aa.bb subnet : 255.255.255.0 gateway: 192.168.aa.1
4. Open my VirtualBox network n I found this:
   IP Address : 192.168.xx.yy subnet: 255.255.255.0
5. Make IP from Wireless as Preferred DNS Server
6. Change subnet from VirtualBox to 255.255.0.0 (because aa different with xx, so I use subnet class B --> 255.255.0.0)
7. And I successfullly login in genymotion to choose n download new virtual device.

So, this is my final setting for VirtualBox network:

IP address: 192.168.cc.dd

Subnet: 255.255.0.0

Default gateway: -empty-

Preferred DNS server: 192.168.aa.bb  --> IP my internet connection (2.1)

Alternate DNS server: -empty-

Hope my answer can help U.

Answer (score 0):

The way i fixed it:

```
1.- Unplug LAN cable, connect to my WiFi network
2.- Retry to sign in to Genymotion
```

And it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

If "Remember my credentials" is checked, try logging in with it unchecked. It asked me my credentials every time, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem, I just unchecked the http proxy setting in Setting->Network->Use http Proxy, and logged in. The problem is solved.
If this does not work go to Genymotion Site and try edit the password and try again.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

(worked with my case)
In your GenyMotion go to:

1. Settings -> Network
2. **Uncheck** Use HTTP Proxy

Answer (score -1):

Just login to the website, https://www.genymotion.com (on your browser) and your problem will be fixed.

If doesn't: Search for your WiFi's server IP (ex. 192.168.1.1).
Go open your **VirtualBox>Preferences>Network>Host-Only Network**.
Edit: **VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter**
Change *IPv4 Address* to your Internet's IP and also all other similar to the former number you've replaced.

Comment: Please try not to answer with "I had this problem too." Plus, another answer here already said the same thing.

Comment: Hey @cricket_007 I've improve my answer so please rank up. ☺

Comment: and guide said to support my answer with personal XP!

Comment: I didn't downvote. The guide should also say not to ask for upvotes. I only upvote answers that personally help me, so since I don't have this problem, I don't think I should do so