# Unknown Generic eroor while login genymotion?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, genymotion

I recently installed genymotion, but when I tried to login into genymotion I am getting this error: 
[image]

Comment: Check google.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756512/genymotion-generic-unknown-error

Comment: Solution does not work work I checked out all.